# How to convert an image from RGB domain to YST domain?

Tags: python

I am a newbie to the YST domain area. I want to convert an RGB 32x32 pixel image into the YST color domain of the same size.
After reading some research papers I got the formula for conversion but not sure how to go about it using python.

[image: I have mentioned the formula.]

Comment: What image file format is the RGB image in?

Comment: @martineau, the image is in jpg format

Comment: In that case I think this could be done with PIL the Python Imaging Library. Is using that third-party module an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy` you can

- build the matrix `.array()`
- multiply it by a vector `.dot(vector)`

```
import numpy as np

x = [[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],[0.147, -0.289, 0.436],[0.615, -0.515, -0.1]]
x = np.array(x)

rgb = [155, 23, 49]
yst = x.dot(rgb)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the conversion as a matrix and multiply it using matrix multiplication:

```py
import numpy as np

x = [[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],[0.147, -0.289, 0.436],[0.615, -0.515, -0.1]]

rgb = [1,2,3]

x = np.matrix(x)

yst = x.dot(rgb)
```

**EDIT:**

To convert your complete image you would have to do:

```py
test_img=np.ones((32,32,3))

x = [[0.299, 0.587, 0.114],[0.147, -0.289, 0.436],[0.615, -0.515, -0.1]]
x = np.array(x)

yst_img = []
for i in range(len(test_img)):
    yst_img.append([])
    for rgb in test_img[i]:
        yst_img[i].append(x.dot(rgb))

 yst_img = np.array(yst_img) #in case you want your data as an array
```

Comment: i have tried replacing the rgb value with my image(img dimension is 32x32 pixel) and it gives me the following error.    File "C:/Python36/seminar_proj/dct_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    yst = x.dot(im)
ValueError: shapes (3,3) and (32,32,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 32 (dim 1)

Comment: the matrix rgb in formula, is it referring to r, g and b component separately in a matrix? if that is the case then i will have to extract each component separately in combine into matrix of 3xn. correct me if i am wrong. thank you.

Comment: Well your image has 32x32 rgb values and you have to do a transformation for each one. So you have to apply the transformation for all rgb vectors.

Comment: @snehanarvekar I added you the rest of the code to convert your image. It would be nice if you could accept my answer.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. The expected output is a 32x32 image in YST domain(i.e after using the formula it has to be stored as an image(32x32 pixel) in jpg format). The dimension of final yst_img when i print is (32, 32, 3).
thank you.

Comment: Well of course it is (32, 32, 3) because each pixel is represented by 3 values in YST. Just as it was before in RGB.

Comment: can you just save the final output in jpg format in a folder?

Comment: @snehanarvekar I do not know how to save an image in a yst-domain, you will have to search for library or function to do that for you or ask a new question on SO for someone to hlep you with that. It would be great if you could accept my answer though, as I answered your original question.

Comment: can you please tell me what's happening in this for loop                               
        for rgb in test_img[i]:
        yst_img[i].append(x.dot(rgb))

Comment: okay, so `rgb` represents your `rgb vector` made up of the three rgb values. I just perform a matrix multiplication with the conversion matrix `x.dot(rgb)` and then I store the result in a list called yst_img.

Comment: conversion from array to image can be done by using imageio.